# bot.owner_id returning None [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I am building a discord bot that has a bot info command...

`bot.owner_id` returns `None`

Code snippet:

```py
@bot.command(aliases=["bi"])
async def bot_info(ctx):
  [...]
  embed.add_field(name="Owner ID", value=str(bot.owner_id))
```

Comment: did u assign the bot.owner_id a value?

Comment: It looks you have not set any user as the bot's owner.

Comment: @Ghost Ops No, but from reading the [API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=owner_id#discord.ext.commands.Bot.owner_id), `bot.owner_id` should get the owner id automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing this out for myself, It kept on returning "None".

An easy workaround would be to store your id as a variable, preferably called "my_id".

```py
#somewhere else in the main file
my_id = yourid

@bot.command(aliases=["bi"])
async def bot_info(ctx):
  [...]
  embed.add_field(name="Owner ID", value = my_id)
```

EDIT: YOU NEED INTENTS

In dev portal and in your bot

They are privileged intents that need to be activated in both dev portal **AND** code

Just add:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all
```

Where you define the bot

Example

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('citrus!', 'citrus?', 'c?', 'c!', 'C!', 'C?'), intents = discord.Intents.All())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a server info command,  I assume you are trying to get the server owner's id?

In that case you should use `Guild.owner_id` and not `owner_id`

Comment: I meant to say bot info and have updated the question accordingly. Sorry!

Comment: oh i see what you mean